# How can I put multiple functions into 1 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

I'm trying to use parameters to solve that, but it doesn't work.
How could I put those 3 functions into 1?
Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button onclick=showText1()>Show text 1</button>
        <button onclick=showText2()>Show text 2</button>
        <button onclick=showText3()>Show text 3</button>
        <p id="text1"></p>
        <p id="text2"></p>
        <p id="text3"></p>
                
    <script>
        function showText1(){
            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "This is a sentence.";
        }

        function showText2(){
            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "This is another sentence.";
        }

        function showText3(){
            document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "This is the third sentence.";
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: Put all the sentences inside one function?

Comment: Each button should generate a specific text, just one function without parameters would show all the three sentences at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `id` to each button according its number, and set the `innerText` of the corresponding paragraph.

```js
function showText(e){
     let id = e.target.id;
     let sentence = "";
     if(id=="1")
          sentence = "This is a sentence.";
     else if(id=="2")
          sentence = "This is another sentence.";
     else if(id=="3")
          sentence = "This is the third sentence.";
     if(sentence)
          document.getElementById(`text${id}`).innerHTML = sentence;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="1" onclick="showText(event)">Show text 1</button>
        <button id="2" onclick="showText(event)">Show text 2</button>
        <button id="3" onclick="showText(event)">Show text 3</button>
        <p id="text1"></p>
        <p id="text2"></p>
        <p id="text3"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Pass Parameter to the function and do action based on the function parameter.

```js
        function showText(type){
           if(type === 'text1') {
               document.getElementById(type).innerHTML = "This is a sentence.";
           }
           else if(type === "text2") {
                document.getElementById(type).innerHTML = "This is another sentence.";
           }
           else if(type === "text3") {
               document.getElementById(type).innerHTML = "This is the third sentence.";
           }

        }
```

```html
        <button onclick=showText('text1')>Show text 1</button>
        <button onclick=showText('text2')>Show text 2</button>
        <button onclick=showText('text3')>Show text 3</button>
        <p id="text1"></p>
        <p id="text2"></p>
        <p id="text3"></p>
```